# Confuse while generating coupon code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have store procedure to generate Coupon Code where i am passing prefix of coupon code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCouponCode1] 
        @Prefix varchar(50),
        @Lenght varchar(50)
    AS
    Begin
    declare @maxID as bigint=0
    declare @PrefixLenght as bigint=0
        set @PrefixLenght=LEN(@Prefix)
    select @maxID = isnull(max(substring(CouponCode,@PrefixLenght+1,@PrefixLenght+1+@Lenght)),0) + 1 from Coupon where CouponCode Like @Prefix + '%'
    select @Prefix + cast(@maxID as VARchar(100))
    end
```

it is working perfect
problem is that 
if in Coupon table there is coupon code like 'FIRST0001' and 'FIRSTNEW001'
here i am getting error - varchar to int conversion fail because of am trying to parse 'NEW001' to int to find max value
is it possible to parse this 'NEW001' to int ignoring starting characters

Comment: Tag dbms used! (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: looks like oracle stored procedure to me but not sure

Comment: i am doing this in MS SQL 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Sql Server` try:

```
select @maxID = isnull(max(substring(CouponCode, patindex('%[0-9]%', CouponCode), len(CouponCode))),0) + 1 
from Coupon where CouponCode Like @Prefix + '%'
```